# White pixeldata is read after the canvas is cleared

Tags: canvas, javafx

I want to read out a `Canvas`'s pixel data (using OpenJFX 12), and do some checks on it.

```
int x = ...;
int y = ...;
Canvas canvas = ...;
WritableImage snapshot = canvas.snapshot(null, null);
PixelReader pixelReader = snapshot.getPixelReader();
Color color = pixelReader.getColor(x, y);
```

This works except that if the canvas were cleared with `canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(...)`, `color` will be `0xffffffff`, which is white, fully visible, but it should be `0x00000000`, as the [documentation says](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#TRANSPARENT). The drawn image is correct, where it sould be transparent, it is, because I see items behind it.

I'm also using TestFX (right now in visible mode), but I don't think that affects the canvas' data.

Why is that? Maybe I misunderstand what `clearRect` do?